# Javascript Force Numeric Only not working in Samsung S4

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have javascript prevent user input letter in the field.

The below code work in iPhone 4/5 and Samsung Galaxy S3 but not working on the S4.

Anyone know of a fix for the S4?

```
$("#postcode").keydown(function (e) 
{
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
      // Allow: Ctrl+A
      (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || 

      // Allow: home, end, left, right
      (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) 
    {
        // let it happen, don't do anything
        return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: How about just setting type to `number`?

Comment: type to number not support all broswer

Comment: Please define "not working". Any errors?

Comment: In iPhone 4/5 and Samsung Galaxy S3 I can only enter number but Samsung Galaxy S4 can enter anything.

Comment: What browsers are you using on the Android devices? The device version itself isn't exactly the relevant point. And while `input type='number'` may not be working in all browsers, clearly this isn't either.

Comment: input type='number' it wrong design and I don't want html5

Comment: @VuthySok - You are ridiculous. Any mobile browser from the last 2 years supports html5 and the input number type.

Comment: @Anthony - Yes html5 last 2 year but my site need support ie7

Comment: You need it to support ie7 ( which not even Microsoft supports ) and iOS/Android? Use http://modernizr.com

Comment: Looks like `preventDefault()` is not working in general for the native browser. You can confirm by trying `$("input").keydown(function (e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
});`

Comment: No wait! It actually seems to only occur when I input characters really fast, which triggers the auto-complete for the keyboard. So probably the autocomplete is somehow shorting out the event handler. You know what would probably work? Not using this code and going with html5 number input with polyfill.

Answer (score 0):

We've got the same kind of issue in Samsung Galaxy S6 as well. So as of me code bellow could be a solution to avoid using keyCode and instead just a value of input text field. You can use this part of code in a keydown event handler method.

```
var isValid = /^[0-9]*$/.test(value);

if (!isValid){
    $(element).val(value.substring(0, value.length - 1));
}
```

Which is checking if user entered something other than number it's just removing it.